# ¿Cómo agregar el contenido de dos ficheros de log en orden de ocurrencia?

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo dos ficheros: `access.log` y `access.log1`, necesito volcar el contenido de ambos en un tercer fichero `navegacion.log` de manera tal que queden en el orden de ocurrencia y a su vez limpiando los ficheros de origen (access.log y access.log1)

Puede suceder que en las horas en que mande a ejecutarse la tarea, el fichero `navegacion.log` ya contenga líneas y estas deben mantenerse, porque es a partir de este archivo que se generan los reportes de navegación en el horario de la medianoche.

Esta tarea se debe ejecutar a las 08:00, 12:00 pm y cada una hora a partir de las 16:00 y hasta las 07:00 del siguiente día. A través del `cron` (esto no es problema).

Es un caso puntual porque mi `ISP` reinicia la cuota de navegación que me asigna en los horarios descritos, y para poder reiniciar la cuota de los usuarios de mi red, pues el fichero `access.log` debe estar limpio.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es simple, `cat` manda el contenido del archivo X a stdout, `>` manda el contenido de stdout a el archivo X (reiniciando el archivo cada vez) y finalmente `>>` agrega el contenido de stdout al archivo X.

```
cat access.log1 > navegacion.log && echo '' > access.log1
cat access.log >> navegacion.log && echo '' > access.log
```

Limpiamos los archivos mandando un string vacío al archivo X usando `echo '' > archivo` y concatenamos la lectura, volcado y limpia del archivo usando `&&`

Comment: en un rato lo pruebo, deja ver qué tal me va !!!